# Running PHP code from erlang

Tags: php, erlang, ejabberd

I am trying to run PHP script from erlang code.Can anybody explain with a simple example?
I am basically trying put some data on google server via this php script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Erlang webserver (Yaws) CAN run PHP scripts, this is an example.

first on the `yaws.conf`, write this.
the env variable.

```
php_exe_path = /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

Also be sure you enable the php processing for the individual server, like this.

```
<server www.example.org>
        port = 80
        listen = 0.0.0.0
        allowed_scripts = php yaws cgi
</server>
```

> Yaws will invoke the php-cgi binary and talk the CGI protocol to the
>   binary.

And thats all, you can run PHP Scripts into Earlang WebServers (Yaws)

Comment: Ethaan:This was very helpful.But could u please elaborate with an example in which php is triggerd by erlang

Comment: this page is not opening could u please suggest some other page

Comment: its a chat room it should work